# Remove class from div with loop/array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have **4 divs** with **same** Class and Id. What I am looking for is to remove `display-none`-class on that specific div whenever `#button` is clicked.

What I have done now is to give an additional class name to each div so they are more *"recognizable"* for jQuery.

Here is my code:

*html*

```
<div class="parentdiv">
  <h3 id="button">remove class</h3>
  <div class="display-none" id="element">
    Show me on button click
  </div>
</div>
```

*jquery*

```
$('h3#button').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('remove-btn-' + (i+1));
});

$('div#element').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('remove-this-' + (i+1));
});
```

So What I am looking for is to loop through `remove-this-1`, `remove-this-2` etc and remove `display-none` class when ever `remove-btn-1`, `remove-btn-2` etc is clicked.

Comment: Couldn't you use the `next` function? `$('#button').on('click', function(){ yourHideFunction($(this).next()); });`

Comment: _I have 4 divs with same Class and Id_, __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__

Comment: Why you need these indexes?

Comment: `$('h3#button').each` This is completely invalid. Id has to be unique.

Comment: Use unique ID's for identify the elements. To remove a class you can use'.removeClass('class_name');'

Comment: didn't get you question. could you please explain more? where your `4 div` with same class and Id?

Comment: @JitendraTiwari `4 divs` are loop in product page and each `div` is a product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use one more class to the `div` which has `display-none` class
2. give same class to each button
3. wrap them in a parent them
4. use `this` to achieve your goal

Whenever you click on the button, it will look for class `box` of current clicked the button. For demo purpose - I have applied CSS to `display-none` class, So that you can see changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
     $(this).prev('.box').removeClass('display-none');
   });
});
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="display-none box">Lorem ispum 0...</div>
  <p class="button">Remove Class</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="display-none box">Lorem ispum 1...</div>
  <p class="button">Remove Class</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="display-none box">Lorem ispum 2...</div>
  <p class="button">Remove Class</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="display-none box">Lorem ispum 3...</div>
  <p class="button">Remove Class</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
   $(this).next().removeClass('display-none');
});
```

```css
.display-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentdiv">
  <h3 class="button">remove class</h3>
  <div class="display-none element">
    Show me on button click 1
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="parentdiv">
  <h3 class="button">remove class</h3>
  <div class="display-none element">
    Show me on button click 2
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="parentdiv">
  <h3 class="button">remove class</h3>
  <div class="display-none element">
    Show me on button click 3
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="parentdiv">
  <h3 class="button">remove class</h3>
  <div class="display-none element">
    Show me on button click 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the id (#) value has to be unique. I suggest you creating unique ids.

For removing a class from an element with jquery you can use the .removeClass('class_name')